# Hide repositories from other layers

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a typical spring boot application with Repositories, Services and Controllers. I would like to be able to block injection of repositories directly in controller but I haven't found a way to do this. In other words: Repositories should be injectable only in services, an attempt to inject in controllers should raise an error. Is it possible?

Comment: Short answer: No

Comment: You might be able to do something leveraging the java access modifiers and using a different package for the controllers.  But Spring has a tendency to reach right across such things and straight into your private variables.  So it probably wouldn't work.